# UITableViewAutomaticDimension is not working

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, ipad, ios7

I had set estimatedheight and height of tableview to UIAutomaticDimension but i am getting increased label height.

I tried changing `label.preferredMaxLayoutWidth` but still not working.

I had set estimatedheight and height of tableview to UIAutomaticDimension but i am getting increased label height.

I tried changing `label.preferredMaxLayoutWidth` but still not working.

func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    if let buildingArr = buildingViolationArray {
        return buildingArr.count
    }
    return 0
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: Language.sharedInstance.isEnglish ? "CELL" : "CELL_AR", for: indexPath) as! BuildingViolationHeaderTableViewCell
    if let buildingViolationsDict = buildingViolationArray?[indexPath.row] {

        cell.followUpNoLbl.text = buildingViolationsDict["followupNo"] as? String
        cell.violationTypeLbl.text = buildingViolationsDict[Language.sharedInstance.isEnglish ? "violationType" : "violationTypeArb"] as? String
        cell.bvBtn.addTarget(self, action: #selector(BuildinVioClicked), for: .touchUpInside)
        if buildingViolationsDict[kIsSelectedKey] as? Bool == true {
            cell.isCellSelected = true
            let buildingVioView = getZoneRegView(buildingViolationsDict)
            buildingVioView.tag = 1
            for removeSubViews in cell.bvStackView.subviews {
                removeSubViews.removeFromSuperview()
                cell.bvStackView.removeArrangedSubview(removeSubViews)
            }

            cell.bvStackView.addArrangedSubview(buildingVioView)
            cell.expandImage.image = UIImage(named: "minus-256")
        } else {
            cell.isCellSelected = false
            for removeSubViews in cell.bvStackView.subviews {
                removeSubViews.removeFromSuperview()
                cell.bvStackView.removeArrangedSubview(removeSubViews)
            }
            cell.expandImage.image = UIImage(named: "plus-256")
        }

        cell.violationTypeLbl.preferredMaxLayoutWidth = cell.violationTypeLbl.frame.size.width
    }

    cell.selectionStyle = .none

    return cell
}

func BuildinVioClicked(sender: UIButton){
    let location = sender.convert(CGPoint.zero, to: bvTableView)
    let indexPath = bvTableView.indexPathForRow(at: location)!
    if var buildingViolationsDict = buildingViolationArray?[indexPath.row] {
        if let isSelect = buildingViolationsDict[kIsSelectedKey] as? Bool, isSelect {
            (buildingViolationArray[indexPath.row])[kIsSelectedKey] = false
        } else {
            (buildingViolationArray[indexPath.row])[kIsSelectedKey] = true
        }
        bvTableView.reloadData()
    }
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    return UITableViewAutomaticDimension
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, estimatedHeightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    return UITableViewAutomaticDimension
}
```

Comment: Please ask question with enough information about problem. Provide code that you have written.

Comment: what have you tried so far? , We are here to help you after you have tried something and it hasn't worked. Try to describe your problem in details.

Comment: Set estimated height to an estimated value not `UITableViewAutomaticDimension ` also make sure you have proper constraint placed for automatic dimension to work properly

Comment: I suggest to try with a simpler cell design just one label inside and see if it works. After that, you can add your design on it and isolate the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Beside setting the `estimatedRowHeight` to `UITableViewAutomaticDimension` (In Swift 4, `UITableViewAutomaticDimension` has been renamed into `UITableView.automaticDimension`). You ought to properly set your cell constraint.

```
class YourCell: UITableViewCell {
  lazy var label: UILabel = {
    let label = UILabel()
    label.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    label.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 12)
    label.numberOfLines = 0 // This property will allow the label according to his content
    return label
  }()

  func addLabelIntoView() {
    contentView.addSubview(label)
    let margin = contentView.layoutMarginsGuide
    NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
      label.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: margin.leadingAnchor),
      label.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: margin.trailingAnchor),
      label.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: margin.topAnchor),
      label.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: margin.bottomAnchor) // Pins bottom of label into the bottom of the view
      ])
  }
}
```